# Create runs of datetime values in dplyr and lubridate

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I would like to create runs of date-time periods (day = between 6 AM and 5:59 PM, night = between 6 PM and 5:59 AM), such that each subsequent period gets its rank.

Each day/night period may contain any number of rows. Sometimes whole periods are missing (for example, day period is followed by day period of the next day - those should get different ranks).

I'm looking specifically for a `dplyr` solution or a solution that can be easily integrated into dplyr workflow.

Here is a data example:

```
structure(list(SubDateTime = structure(c(1555187547, 1555194755, 
1555231810, 1555573511, 1555664546, 1555702679, 1555704545, 1555706119, 
1555707855, 1555709640, 1555713244, 1555722752, 1555753649, 1555837869
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Desired output:

```
   SubDateTime           Rank
   <dttm>                <dbl>
 1 2019-04-13 20:32:27       1
 2 2019-04-13 22:32:35       1
 3 2019-04-14 08:50:10       2
 4 2019-04-18 07:45:11       3
 5 2019-04-19 09:02:26       4
 6 2019-04-19 19:37:59       5
 7 2019-04-19 20:09:05       5
 8 2019-04-19 20:35:19       5
 9 2019-04-19 21:04:15       5
10 2019-04-19 21:34:00       5
11 2019-04-19 22:34:04       5
12 2019-04-20 01:12:32       5
13 2019-04-20 09:47:29       6
14 2019-04-21 09:11:09       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(Rank = rleid(floor((as.numeric(SubDateTime) - 21600)/43200))) 

   SubDateTime           key
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2019-04-13 20:32:27     1
 2 2019-04-13 22:32:35     1
 3 2019-04-14 08:50:10     2
 4 2019-04-18 07:45:11     3
 5 2019-04-19 09:02:26     4
 6 2019-04-19 19:37:59     5
 7 2019-04-19 20:09:05     5
 8 2019-04-19 20:35:19     5
 9 2019-04-19 21:04:15     5
10 2019-04-19 21:34:00     5
11 2019-04-19 22:34:04     5
12 2019-04-20 01:12:32     5
13 2019-04-20 09:47:29     6
14 2019-04-21 09:11:09     7
```

Comment: `dplyr` now includes the function `consecutive_id()` so you don't need to use `data.table::rleid()`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thank you for a new function! I didn't know that function is avaliable on `dplyr` :)

Comment: @Park thank you! The solution works, but I can't quite grasp how. I understand that you subtract 6 hours and divide by 12 hours, but what does the resulting value show?

Comment: @PolinaB `data.table::rleid` or `dplyr::consecutive_id` gives run length type group id. Take a look at [rleid](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.8/topics/rleid) or [consecutive_id](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/consecutive_id.html)

Comment: @Park I understand how the function works, thanks. I don't quite get why you subtracted 6 hours and divided by 12. I'd appreciate it if you could explain! I have more similar tasks for different time periods (e.g., crate runs of observations that were collected less than 3 days apart).

Comment: @PolinaB I subtract 6H and divide by 12, then apply `floor` beacause your task separate day and night, that day starts from 6 A.M and it's period is 12 H